# Конвертация изображений

Tags: ubuntu

Как переконвертировать большое количество изображений в формат JPG, фотошоп, пдф и корал (не уверен что правильно так называется) в убунте 11,04?

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас, как назло, нет никакого юникса под рукой, но это будет что-то в таком духе

```
find /path/to/images -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec convert '{}' '{}'.png \;
```

Почитайте man по утилите `convert` из набора `ImageMagic`. Эта штука умеет многое.